# What is the maximum value for the Resource ID in PHP?

Tags: php, gmp

I have a PHP script that runs constantly (or at least it should).  It is a simple program that loops through numbers and tests them for primality.  Unfortunately this script crashes about every 12 hours or so with the following error:

```
"PHP Warning:  gmp_strval(): -2147483648 is not a valid GMP integer resource"
```

I'm guessing that I'm exceeding the Resource ID max value when assigning this Resource to a variable and when the script attempts to run a function against that variable it crashes.

So, what is the max Resource ID?  More importantly, how can I avoid this issue?

The code is a bit long but I'll try to give you the gist:

```
$NumberToTest = gmp_init("$StartingString",10);
/* Time to test for primality */
while(1)
{
// Test $NumberToTest for primality.
$NumberToTest = gmp_add($NumberToTest,2);
}
```

Comment: As -2147483648 is PHP_INT_MAX + 1 on a 32-bit system, I'd suggest the maximum is probably PHP_INT_MAX.... if you can switch to a 64-bit version of PHP, it would probably eliminate the problem

Comment: I'm on a 64-bit system and here is the output of "php -v": PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:24:35) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not re-use resource IDs internally, so eventually you'll hit a problem with PHP using them all up, causing the warning you got. See the [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47396). Since a bunch of things in PHP will register a resource, incrementing the resource ID, this bug is easy to encounter in long running scripts.

The max ID depends on your architecture. You can print the constant PHP_INT_MAX to get the number for your install, but on 32 bit systems it's generally 2,147,483,647. It's significantly higher on 64 bit systems. Mine prints out 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. You're pretty unlikely to exhaust the resource ID limit on 64 bit systems.